# VSCodeでインストールした拡張機能がメニューに出てこなくなった

Tags: html, vscode

**【現状】**
以前、VSCodeでHTMLを書いていました。
その際、拡張機能を色々とインストールしたのですが、その中にPreview機能もありました。
それを使って、VSCodeでコードを書きながらHTMLプレビューをし確認するといった作業をやっていました。

その後、Pythonを書く機会があってPythonをインストールし、使っていました。

その後、またしばらく日が経ってからまたHTMLを書く機会があり、VSCodeで書こうとしたのですが、
今回は今までインストールした拡張機能をメニューから確認することが出来なくなっていることに気づきました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、HTML上で右クリックをするとプレビューが出てきたのですが、今回は出て来ておらず困っています。
[![画像の説明をここに入力][2]][2]

**【考えたこと】**
もしかしたらPythonをインストールしたためにVSCodeがPythonモードになっていてHTML拡張機能が出てこないとか・・？とか
色々と考えたのですが、分からずです。

また、メニューに拡張機能がない件でも色々とググったのですが、それらしい対策方法は見当たりませんでした。

ちなみに、拡張機能自体はちゃんとインストールされていることが確認できています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

それなのに、HTML→Python→HTMLだと拡張機能が出てこなくなるのは困っています。

どうやればまた出るようになるのでしょうか？
こういう経験がある方いますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

スクリーンショット右下を見るからに、ファイルをDjangoのテンプレートとしてのHTMLとして開いていることが原因のように見えます。

この部分をクリックする、またはコマンドパレットで**Select Language Mode**を選択する[など](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file)をすると言語モードの選択画面が出てくるのでHTMLを選択してみてください。

設定ファイルでシステム全体やプロジェクトごとの拡張子に対するデフォルト言語モードの設定も可能です。